# Replace multiple XML attribute values in all records with Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

### Problem

My MSSQL database has a table `records` with an XML column `data`, which is used like this:

```
<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-GB">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-GB">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>
```

I want to update **all rows** in the table at once, replacing `/record/field/@lang` by `en-US` where it is `en-GB` at the moment (all elements with that attribute value).

Already tried something like...

```
declare @i int;
declare @xml xml;
set @xml = (select top(1) [data] from [my-database].[dbo].[records]);
select @i = @xml.value('count(/record/field[lang="en-GB"])', 'int')

while @i > 0
begin
    set @xml.modify('
            replace value of
                (/record/field[lang="en-GB"]/text())[1]
            with "en-US"
    ')

    set @i = @i - 1
end

select @xml;
```

... but it returns the data unchanged and only works if a single row is selected. How can I make this work and update all rows in one go?

### Solution

I ended up using XQuery as suggested by Shnugo. My slightly generalized query looks like this:

```
UPDATE [my-database].[dbo].[records] SET data = data.query(N'
    <record>
    {
        for $attr in /record/@*
        return $attr
    }
    {
        for $fld in /record/*
        return
        if (local-name($fld) = "field")
        then <field>
        {
            for $attr in $fld/@*
            return
            if (local-name($attr) = "lang" and $attr = "en-GB")
            then attribute lang {"en-US"}
            else $attr
        }
        {$fld/node()}
        </field>
        else $fld
    }
    </record>
')
FROM [my-database].[dbo].[records]
WHERE [data].exist('/record/field[@lang="en-GB"]') = 1;
SELECT * FROM [my-database].[dbo].[records]
```

The name of the top most node `<record>` needs to be hard-coded it seems, because MSSQL server doesn't support dynamic element names (nor attribute names). Its attributes as well as all child elements other than `<field>` are copied automatically with above code.

Comment: Great question, great solution 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add this as a second answer, as it follows a completely different approach. The following code will use `.query()` with a `FLWOR` query to read the XML *as-is* but change the attribute `lang`, when the content is `en_GB`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-GB">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-GB">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>';
```

The query

```
SELECT @xml.query
(N'
    <record id="{/record/@id}">
    {
        for $fld in /record/field
        return <field>
        {
            for $attr in $fld/@*
            return
            if(local-name($attr)="lang" and $attr="en-GB") then attribute lang {"en-US"}
            else $attr
        }
        {$fld/text()}
        </field>
    }
    </record>
')
```

The result

```
<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-US">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-US">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>
```

### UPDATE: This works with all table's rows too:

Try this to update a full table at once:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXml XML)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(
N'<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-GB">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-GB">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>'
)
,(
N'<record id="2">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-GB">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-GB">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>'
);

UPDATE @tbl SET YourXml=YourXml.query
(N'
    <record id="{/record/@id}">
    {
        for $fld in /record/field
        return <field>
        {
            for $attr in $fld/@*
            return
            if(local-name($attr)="lang" and $attr="en-GB") then attribute lang {"en-US"}
            else $attr
        }
        {$fld/text()}
        </field>
    }
    </record>
');

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Comment: Definitely the cleanest solution. Much appreciated! I tried to generalize the code as much as possible and appended my final solution to my question. Let me know if there is anything I could improve, such as not hardcoding `<record>` as top most element.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I'm glad to read this! Your own solution looks great  Just keep in mind, that this might rearrange your XML.

Comment: It does change the order, but XML does not guarantee it anyway. Each repeatable field has an occurrence number in my data to retain its relative position within its group. The order of `<field>` and adjacent elements does not matter to me. Thanks again!

Comment: @CoDEmanX Well, this is not entirely true. XML is - by definition - an ordered set of elements. The order is an implicit part of the document. This is not true for attributes. Furthermore you can enforce the order using an XSD with `xs:sequence`. And there are *canonical XML documents*, where the order of attributes must be in descending alphabetical order. This can be very important for signatures...

Comment: Oh thanks, looks like I was hornswoggled by false information. I changed my solution to iterate over all fields and enter a `then` branch with some special handling if the name is `field`, otherwise return the elements unchanged. Element order is retained this way, should be as generic as possible now 

Comment: "Definitely the cleanest solution".  You have a VERY strange definition of clean.  The only reason this solution is at all usable is thanks to the meticulous formatting of the multi line statement.  This is pretty awful really.  SQL servers XML support is just so castrated/antiquated.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution without `xquery, xpath`...:

```
  DECLARE @xml XML = N'<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-GB">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-GB">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>'

SET @xml = REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS nvarchar(max)), '"en-GB"', '"en-US"')

SELECT @xml
```

And use `modify()`

```
DECLARE @nodeCount int
DECLARE @i int

SET @i = 1

SELECT @nodeCount = @xml.value('count(/record/field/@lang)','int') 

WHILE (@i <= @nodeCount)
BEGIN
    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/record/field/@lang)[.="en-GB"][1] with "en-US"')
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @xml
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/YIUQ47393)

Comment: Can you expand your answer on how to use the second example on multiple records in an existing table? (You should it for a single record, that you defined in-line)

Comment: This actually worked for me. Very simple solution... Thanks!

Comment: How is this ugly?  Compared to the accepted answer it is far simpler, more easily understood for most developers and shorter.  You are still using XPath by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately, the `replace value of` statement only updates one node at a time. So in your case, a quick and dirty replace would be the easiest to write (and, with luck, maybe even the fastest to run):

```
update t set [data] = cast(
  replace(cast(t.[data] as nvarchar(max)), N' lang="en-GB"', N' lang="en-US"')
as xml)
from dbo.Records t
where t.[data].exist('/record/field[@lang="en-GB"]') = 1;
```

If you XML schema varies such as that there is no guarantee that the `/record` node will be always at the top level, you might want to modify the filter as such:

```
where t.[data].exist('//record/field[@lang="en-GB"]') = 1;
```

Another approach would be to use a FLWOR statement, but if the XML structure varies significantly and contains other unpredictable nodes, it becomes rather difficult not to lose anything accidentally. Which in turn will lead to poorer performance. For this approach to be viable, your XML schema has to be very stable.

Comment: This would replace `"en-GB"` in the entire XML including text nodes if I see that correctly, which seems a little insecure. It looks like the solution with the least amount of code however. Thanks.

Comment: @CoDEmanX On string level you can replace `lang="en-GB"` with `lang="en_US"` (with a leading blank) to minimize this danger...

Comment: @CoDEmanX, yes, insecure, though Shnugo's remark makes it more viable. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid the cast to a string type due to side effects (but this might be the easiest approach, especially if the XML might include other nodes, which you do not show in your example...)

I'd avoid loops too.

My approach was to shredd and re-create the XML:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en-GB">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en-GB">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>';
```

--The query will read all field's values and rebuild the XML with the changed language

```
WITH Shredded AS
(
    SELECT fld.value(N'@tag',N'nvarchar(max)') AS tag
          ,fld.value(N'@occ',N'int') AS occ
          ,fld.value(N'@lang',N'nvarchar(max)') AS lang
          ,fld.value(N'(./text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS content
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/record/field') AS A(fld)
)
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/record/@id)[1]',N'int') AS [@id]
     ,(
        SELECT   tag AS [@tag]
                ,occ AS [@occ]
                ,CASE WHEN lang='en-GB' THEN 'en_US' ELSE lang END AS [@lang]
                ,content AS [*]
        FROM Shredded
        FOR XML PATH('field'),TYPE
      ) AS [*]
FOR XML PATH(N'record')
```

The result

```
<record id="1">
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="de-DE">Höhe</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="1" lang="en_US">height</field>
  <field tag="WA">173</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="de-DE">Breite</field>
  <field tag="DI" occ="2" lang="en_US">width</field>
  <field tag="WA">55</field>
  <field tag="EE">cm</field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks. It would lose all nodes however, that are not shredded/re-created explicitly, which is undesired in my case.

Comment: @CoDEmanX, yeah, that's why I wrote *especially if the XML might include other nodes*... Any *structured* approach can get into troubles, if you do not know the **full** structure in advance. My second answer with the `FLWOR XQuery` is more flexible with this... But the simple `cast and replace` approach might be the best for you...

Comment: The structure is dynamic in my use case, so the structured approach isn't viable. But I really appreciate that you showed this option too.